# Почему условие в цикле while не выполняется?

Tags: java, while

Всем привет. Написал свою первую программу - "Камень, ножницы, бумага". Вроде всё работает, кроме одного НО: в цикле while не выполняется условие и программа не завершается. Помогите разобраться

```
public class Stone_scissors_paper {

public static int PersonCount;
public static int BotCount;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What's your name?");
    String name = scn.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Hello " + name + ". Let's play an interesting game? Say Yes or No?");
    String answer = scn.next();

    // Check the entered answer
    while (!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
        System.out.println("Your answer is incorrect, try once more)");
        answer = scn.next();
    }

    System.out.println("Okay, let's go. You first");

    String BotChoose;
    int round = 0;
    int[] game = new int[1];

    // Game till 3 wins
    while ((PersonCount != 3) || (BotCount != 3)) {

        round ++;
        System.out.println("Round " + round + " is:");
        String Mychoose = scn.next();

        if (Mychoose.equalsIgnoreCase("Stone"))
        {
            System.out.println("You pick " + Mychoose);
            BotChoose = Bot.ChooseBot();
            System.out.println("My pick is " + BotChoose);
            game = Compare.CompareGame(Mychoose, BotChoose);
        }

        else if (Mychoose.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors"))
        {
            System.out.println("You pick " + Mychoose);
            BotChoose = Bot.ChooseBot();
            System.out.println("My pick is " + BotChoose);
            game = Compare.CompareGame(Mychoose, BotChoose);
        }

        else if (Mychoose.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper"))
        {
            System.out.println("You pick " + Mychoose);
            BotChoose = Bot.ChooseBot();
            System.out.println("My pick is " + BotChoose);
            game = Compare.CompareGame(Mychoose, BotChoose);
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("You input incorrect word, please try once more");
        }

        System.out.println("PersonCount = " + PersonCount + " BotCount = " + 
BotCount);
        System.out.println("Round " + round + " is over\n");

 // Программа корректно работает только с этим условием, хотя оно лишнее
        if(PersonCount == 3 || BotCount == 3)
            break;
    }
    if(game[0] == 3)
        System.out.println("Damn, you win!!!");
    else
        System.out.println("Ahaha, you lost!!!");

    }
}
```

Также прикладываю 2 метода, которые используются в программе. Может быть в них закралась какая-то ошибка, я не знаю.
Метод CompareGame класса Compare:

```
public class Compare {
public static int[] CompareGame(String PersonChoose, String BotChoose){

    if (PersonChoose.equalsIgnoreCase("Stone")){

        if (BotChoose.equals("Stone")){
            System.out.println("Draw, please try once more");
        }

        if (BotChoose.equals("Scissors")){
            System.out.println("You win");
            Stone_scissors_paper.PersonCount += 1;
        }

        if (BotChoose.equals("Paper")){
            System.out.println("I win");
            Stone_scissors_paper.BotCount += 1;
        }
    }

    if (PersonChoose.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors")){

        if (BotChoose.equals("Scissors")){
            System.out.println("Draw, please try once more");
        }

        if (BotChoose.equals("Paper")){
            System.out.println("You win");
            Stone_scissors_paper.PersonCount += 1;
        }

        if (BotChoose.equals("Stone")){
            System.out.println("I win");
            Stone_scissors_paper.BotCount += 1;
        }

    }

    if (PersonChoose.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper")) {

        if (BotChoose.equals("Paper")) {
            System.out.println("Draw, please try once more");
        }

        if (BotChoose.equals("Stone")) {
            System.out.println("You win");
            Stone_scissors_paper.PersonCount += 1;

        }

        if (BotChoose.equals("Scissors")) {
            System.out.println("I win");
            Stone_scissors_paper.BotCount += 1;
        }
    }
    return new int[] {Stone_scissors_paper.PersonCount, Stone_scissors_paper.BotCount};
    }
}
```

Метод ChooseBot класса Bot:

```
public class Bot {
private static String PickBot;
private static String[] BotPick = {"Stone", "Scissors", "Paper"};
private static Random RandNum = new Random();

public static String ChooseBot(){
    // Возвращает числа от 0 до 2
    int rnd = RandNum.nextInt(3);
    switch (rnd){
        case 0:
            PickBot = BotPick[0];
            return PickBot;

        case 1:
            PickBot = BotPick[1];
            return PickBot;

        case 2:
            PickBot = BotPick[2];
            return PickBot;

        default:
            System.out.println("Something went wrong");
            return "error";
        }
    }
}
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: Ваше условие `if(PersonCount == 3 || BotCount == 3)` прерывает цикл, если хотя бы ОДНО из значений равно 3. Условие же `while ((PersonCount != 3) || (BotCount != 3))` продолжает цикл если хотя бы одно из значений не равно 3 — то есть прервёт только когда ОБА значения будут равны 3.

Comment: @andreymal спасибо за разъяснения. И как тогда поступить в данной ситуации?

Comment: Смотря что вам нужно, но что-то мне подсказывает, что в while нужно запихнуть условие, противоположное тому что в if. Но это настолько элементарно, что мне лень писать готовое решение)

Comment: И нет, сейчас у вас там условие не противоположное

Answer (score 1):

Абсолютно бесполезная штука :  int[] game = new int[1]

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stone_scissors_paper {

public static int PersonCount;
public static int BotCount;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What's your name?");
    String name = scn.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Hello " + name + ". Let's play an interesting game? Say Yes or No?");
    String answer = scn.next();

    // Check the entered answer
    while (!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
        System.out.println("Your answer is incorrect, try once more)");
        answer = scn.next();
    }

    System.out.println("Okay, let's go. You first");

    String BotChoose;
    int round = 0;

    // Game till 3 wins
    while (PersonCount < 3 || BotCount < 3) {
        round++;
        System.out.println("Round " + round + " is:");
        String Mychoose = scn.next();

        if (Mychoose.equalsIgnoreCase("Stone") 
                || Mychoose.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors")
                || Mychoose.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper")) {
            System.out.println("You pick " + Mychoose);
            BotChoose = Bot.ChooseBot();
            System.out.println("My pick is " + BotChoose);
            Compare.CompareGame(Mychoose, BotChoose);
        } else {
            System.out.println("You input incorrect word, please try once more");
        }

        System.out.println("PersonCount = " + PersonCount + " BotCount = " + BotCount);
        System.out.println("Round " + round + " is over\n");
        if (PersonCount == 3) {
            System.out.println("Damn, you win!!!");
            break;
        } else if (BotCount == 3) {
            System.out.println("Ahaha, you lost!!!");
        }
    }

}
}
```

Переписать метод на

```
public static void CompareGame(String PersonChoose, String BotChoose)
```

он все равно меняет вашу глобальную переменную, не надо ему ничего возвращать типа вашего извращения :)
Compare класс:

```
public class Compare {
public static void CompareGame(String PersonChoose, String BotChoose) {

    if (PersonChoose.equalsIgnoreCase("Stone")) {
        if (BotChoose.equals("Paper")) {
            System.out.println("I win");
            Stone_scissors_paper.BotCount += 1;
        } else if (BotChoose.equals("Scissors")) {
            System.out.println("You win");
            Stone_scissors_paper.PersonCount += 1;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Draw, please try once more");
        }
    }

    if (PersonChoose.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors")) {
        if (BotChoose.equals("Paper")) {
            System.out.println("You win");
            Stone_scissors_paper.PersonCount += 1;
        } else if (BotChoose.equals("Stone")) {
            System.out.println("I win");
            Stone_scissors_paper.BotCount += 1;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Draw, please try once more");
        }
    }

    if (PersonChoose.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper")) {
        if (BotChoose.equals("Stone")) {
            System.out.println("You win");
            Stone_scissors_paper.PersonCount += 1;
        } else if (BotChoose.equals("Scissors")) {
            System.out.println("I win");
            Stone_scissors_paper.BotCount += 1;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Draw, please try once more");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Бот класс:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Bot {
private static String[] BotPick = {"Stone", "Scissors", "Paper"};
private static Random RandNum = new Random();

public static String ChooseBot(){
// Возвращает числа от 0 до 2
int rnd = RandNum.nextInt(3);
switch (rnd){
    case 0:
        return BotPick[0];
    case 1:
        return BotPick[1];
    case 2:
        return BotPick[2];
    default:
        System.out.println("Something went wrong");
        return "error";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Я понял свои недочёты, благодарю за разъяснения